# Retrieving the return value of an insert...value 'return into' statement using codeigniter (oracle oci 8)

Tags: sql, oracle, codeigniter, plsql, oci8

Firstly I apologise if this is a duplicate!

Say I have a PL/SQL anonymous block stored in a PHP variable `$sql`, ready to be executed and is laid out thus:

```
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME(PARAM1, PARAM2, PARAM3)
  VALUES(?,?,?)
  RETURNING TABLE_NAME.PARAM1 INTO ?;
END;
```

Using the Codeigniter framework, I want to be able to perform this statement:

```
$query = $this->db->query($sql, array('1', 'Hello', 'World', $id));
```

...and then be able to access the returned variable of '1', which should be stored in the `$id` variable.

I know that the syntax I have provided wouldn't necessarily work, I've just used it to demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve.

I don't believe the OCI8 driver is equipped to handle returning variables from a statement in this way. I can't seem to find a way to manually bind a variable (in this case `$id`) to the RETURN...INTO clause of the PL/SQL statement. Normally I could do:

`oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':id', $id) //replace '?' with ':id' on the RETURN...INTO section of the anonymous block`

...However, I have tried to implement this using the `$this->db->call_function()` but that did not work either. I have been digging around the code to try and find a way to extend the driver to do this but I fear I may be complicating things or I am going about it the wrong way.

**EDITED QUESTION 8/4/14:**

**I know how to select a column variable I want to return. What I'm unsure about is how I can bind that returned variable to a PHP variable inside the codeigniter framework.**

Super thanks in advance! :)

**EDIT 1:**

1. I've edited the question to be clearer (emboldened above.)
2. I'm using the returned value as a foreign key in subsequent statements.
3. I'm auto incrementing the 'PARAM1' column using a trigger and a sequence.

Comment: p.s. I'm willing to try and elaborate further if needed. I'm a bit unsure of how to proceed but I hope that didn't confuse my question! :)

Comment: How are you incrementing this column? Oracle sequence and table trigger? In the application code? If you are using a sequence but not a trigger, you could select the nextval in your code, and then use that in your insert and for other references.

Comment: Hi Wolf, I'm using triggers and sequences to increment the column, yeah. I commented further on Calipso's answer below trying to explain what I'm after a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has a unique identifier in all tables called rowid.

pleasce check the following select statement

```
select rowid, *
from ANYTABLE;
```

you can get the rowid of the inserted record by

```
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME(PARAM1, PARAM2, PARAM3)
  VALUES(?,?,?)
  RETURNING rowid INTO  my_output_variable_;
END;
```

Comment: Rowid's are not permanent and cannot be reliably used to identify a persistent record. [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm), and [Ask Tom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:53140678334596).

Comment: The rowid changes when the database is exported and imported to an other instance or things like that. If you just want to get the related record just after you insert it (probably you want to do related actions with this record) it is as trustable as the key values are.

Comment: I would agree one can rely on the rowid for immediate access to the record, such as for an immediate subsequent update. But it cannot be relied on as a foreign key or a persistent reference to that record (I'm not sure what the OP is doing with the ID).

Comment: Thanks for your input so far guys. I'm using the ID as a foreign key in subsequent statements. I know how to select a column variable I want to return. What I'm unsure about is how I can bind that returned variable to a PHP variable inside the codeigniter framework. I hope that helps! Sorry if I'm being confused ha ha.